# Sketch: Can I round the end of a line vector?

Tags: vector, sketch-app

When you draw a line using the vector tool in Sketch, the end is squared.
Is there a way to change it to a round cap similar to the option in the Stroke panel in Illustrator?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can select your border and then click on the cog symbol at the borders panel. Then choose your ends and joins in the dropdown, that appears.

[image]

Comment: Ah. As a new Sketch user... there's so much functionality hidden behind that "cog." Thanks @Afterlame

Comment: hmm...That had no effect for me. :(